# npm install jquery bootstrap but not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, npm-install

I used npm to install Bootstrap and jQuery and using webpack to bundle them, but when I'm loading up my page on http-server, I get "jQuery is not defined". Below is what I have in my component files and my json.package

```
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install --save jquery


require('bootstrap');
window.$ = $;
var $ = require('jquery');
```

//json.package

```
{
  "name": "API_Assignment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-addons-update": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
}
```

I fixed it by including the below in my index but I don't understand why do I have to do this when I've required the bootstrap and jquery module already?

```
<script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

//webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./api_assignment.jsx",
  output: {
    path: "./",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you post your webpack configuration? It seems like jQuery is not getting added to your `bundle.js` file.

Comment: @jrubins just added!